# Slope stability using the Riemann-Roch theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I am studying about the (Stability on a curve). Suppose $C$ is a smooth curve of genus g. The Riemann-Roch
theorem asserts that if $E$ is a coherent sheaf on $C$ then the Euler characteristic of $E $ is $\chi(E)= deg(E)+ r(E)(1-g)$

Polarizing $C$ with $H = p$ a point, we find

Then The Hilbert polynomial    $P(E,m)= \chi(E(m))$  $=deg(E(m))+r(E)(1-g)$.

My question is how can we rewrite these equation to become  $r(E)m +(deg(E)+r(E)(1-g))$?
Where $E(m)$ Is the twisted sheaf

Comment: Crossposting from [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3743995/slope-stability-using-the-riemann-roch-theorem) after such a short period of time is not within community norms. One should also link cross-posts together to prevent the duplication of work.